# AAD Hybrid - moving user from different forest while migrating Office 365 mailbox

Tags: migration, office365

This is a very specific scenario, hope someone can shed some light.
Assuming we have AAD company.com synched with AD users from contoso.local (contoso.com) and with AD users from business.local (business.com), two different forests.
We need to migrate Office 365 mailboxes while also migrating users from business.local to contoso.local in a way as such user jon.doe@business.com becomes jon.doe@contoso.com but keeping mailboxes, SharePoint rights, Teams conversations and shares.

What's the best practice?
Right now seems to be:

- move business.local user to OU not synched with AAD
- find user in Admin Center and restore it
- create user in contoso.local entering email address and proxyaddress fields
- get new user ObjectGUID
- get GUID2ImmutableID
- set-MsolUser jon.doe@business.com -immutableid

but process for one single user is taking forever and I have no guaranties Sharepoint access and Teams history is preserved.
Is there an issue on system level in UPN changes and what impact this may have?

Answer (score 0):

You should use ADMT (or similar tools) to migrate user accounts between different forests while preserving all their existing attributes.

If you delete user accounts from forest A and create new user accounts in forest B, there's no way for ADConnect to match them.